# Run tasks in different threads

Tags: java, multithreading

How can I run my task N-times in M-threads? For example, I have some task

```
public static Runnable createTask () {
   Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
     @Override
     public void run() {               
        System.out.println("simple task");
     }
   };
return runnable;
}
```

I need to run this task N-times and divide the work into M-threads.

Comment: Use `ExecutorService` - specifically https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html#newFixedThreadPool%28int%29

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go. If you want same task to run "N" time, then create "N" `Callable` instance of same task and add it in the `Callable` `List` which you will pass to `invokeAll` method.

```
      try {
        List<Callable<Object>> callableList = new ArrayList<Callable<Object>>();
        callableList.add(null); /*Add instance of Callable*/
        callableList.add(null); /*Add instance of Callable*/
        callableList.add(null); /*Add instance of Callable*/

        //Specify how many threads you want or need to operate. Read other methods of Executors which return different instances of ExecutorService
        final ExecutorService service = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(3);

        //This will invoke all your N tasks in specified M threads ...
        service.invokeAll(callableList);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```